# active record attributes rules during updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I work on home renting application. `Homes` can offer a swimming pool access and some of them will also have an alarm (so children can be safe).

I would like to add the following "rules" on how the boolean attributes `home.with_swimming_pool_alarm` and `home.with_swimming_pool` depend on each other.

```rb
it 'should be invalid to have an alarm but no swimming pool' do

    home = build(:home, with_swimming_pool_alarm: true, with_swimming_pool: false)
    expect(home).to be_invalid
end


it 'alarm= true  => swimming_pool==true' do

    home = create(:home, with_swimming_pool_alarm: true)
    expect(home.with_swimming_pool).to be_truthy
end

it 'should reset with_swimming_pool_alarm' do

    home = create(:home, with_swimming_pool: true, with_swimming_pool_alarm: true)
    home.update(with_swimming_pool: false)
    expect(home.with_swimming_pool_alarm).to be_nil
end
```

**How can I do it ?**

I find these rules quite simple to explain but not so easy to implement them.
Also, in this example, there are only 2 boolean depending on each other, but in reality, there are over 50 flags.

Answer (score 0):

In relation to your first example, you can write a validation that a boolean has a specific value (such as true or false).

```rb
class Home
  validates :with_swimming_pool, inclusion: [true], if: -> { with_swimming_pool_alarm? }
end
```